# URL rewriting with Isapi_Rewrite 2 on Windows shared hosting fails partially

Tags: asp-classic, iis-6, isapi-rewrite, helicontech

I have been forced to switch from IIRF to Isapi_Rewrite due to moving to a shared hosting environment from a VPS. The URL rewrites I was using under IIRF should work with minimal modifications, but for some unknown reason only one of the rewrites works.

Here's my httpd.ini for ISAPI_REWRITE V2:

```
[ISAPI_Rewrite]

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule /buy-sell-assets$ /search/Assets.asp

ReWriteRule .*trucks-tractor\.html$ /search/NewSearch.asp?cat_id=157

RewriteRule .*trucks-rigid\.html$ /search/NewSearch.asp?cat_id=10

ReWriteRule .*trailers\.html$ /search/NewSearch.asp?cat_id=4

ReWriteRule .*helicopters\.html$ /search/NewSearch.asp?cat_id=481

ReWriteRule .*aircraft-fixedwing\.html$ /search/NewSearch.asp?cat_id=467

ReWriteRule .*aircraft-fixed-wing\.html$ /search/NewSearch.asp?cat_id=467

ReWriteRule .*buses\.html$ /search/NewSearch.asp?cat_id=3

ReWriteRule .*boats\.html$ /search/NewSearch.asp?cat_id=559

ReWriteRule .*cars\.html$ /search/NewSearch.asp?cat_id=8

ReWriteRule .*crushers\.html$ /search/NewSearch.asp?cat_id=635

ReWriteRule .*screens\.html$ /search/NewSearch.asp?cat_id=637

ReWriteRule .*cranes\.html$ /search/NewSearch.asp?cat_id=430

ReWriteRule .*equipment\.html$ /search/NewSearch.asp?cat_id=12
```

The *really* odd thing is that the rewrite rule

```
RewriteRule .*trucks-rigid\.html$ /search/NewSearch.asp?cat_id=10
```

works, but none of the others do. They are all pointing to the exact same script, so I'm at a complete loss as to why the others aren't working.

```
Here's the working URL: 
http://www.atn.co.za/buy-sell-assets/trucks-rigid.html

Here's one of the non-working URLs: 
http://www.atn.co.za/buy-sell-assets/trailers.html
```

Why should one work and not the others? This is an incredibly frustrating issue, I've been trying various permutations for about four hours now and I'm about to do something drastic :(

If anyone can provide any insight or assistance on this I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following format:

```
RewriteRule /buy-sell-assets/trucks-tractor\.html$ /search/NewSearch.asp?cat_id=157 [I,L]
```

make sure each rule ends with [NC,L] or you'll have all your pages pointing at one script.